# how to  write data into csv from db table?

Tags: c#-3.0

Possible ways to write data into csv file from table or stored procedure?

Comment: You need to post a code snippet of what you're doing. Are you using a string or a stringbuilder? Are you writing each row to the file immediately or buffering first? etc. These choices play a big role on speed as you'll bottleneck in different parts of the system. Have you also ran a profiler to find the bottleneck in your existing code?

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly dealing with 2 bottlenecks - Network and DiskIO. If your database is large dumping the entirety of it to a flat file can take a while. Attempt to parallise the db query if your database is clustered: Grab ranges of data convert them to CSV in memory in parallel and once you have large enough block in memory commit to the file on disk.